# Client/Server design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, client-server

I am new in programming and I want to code a simple Client Server System where the Client sends commands like "SAY house" and the Server detects the keyword "SAY" as an command and returns whatever is after the keyword (in this case "house"). There are many examples how to do this but what I also want to learn with this project is a good design pattern for problems like this. I dont want to implement everything in only 2 classes like Server.java and Client.java.

So I started with a Server class who starts the server on a port and waits for clients. When he get a Request from a client, the Server class delegates the input to a class "RequestHandler". This class does the switch-case part to detect a command like "Say" or "SHUTDOWN" and calls over an interface the corresponding method.

Is this a good pattern? The problem is for example the service "SHUTDOWN". I have to take the Socket Object all along with me to the method who executes the command. Or maybe this pattern isnt good for upgrading the Server with more Functions? Help please for improvements!

Thanks

---

```
public class Server {
private int port;
private ServerSocket server;

public Server(int port) throws Exception{
    this.port = port;
    try{
          server = new ServerSocket(port);      
     }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Server kann nicht gestartet werden: "+e.getMessage());
          throw e;
     }
}

public Server(int port){
    this.port = port;
}

public void start(){
    Socket client;
    Thread thread;

    while (true) {
        try {
            client = server.accept();
            // Verbindung eingegangen, Objekt erzeugen und in Thread laufen lassen
            System.out.println("Verbindung von "+client.getInetAddress());
            CommandHandler handler = new CommandHandlerImpl(client,new ControllerImpl());
            thread = new Thread(handler);
            thread.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Verbindungsfehler: "+e);
        }
      }
}
```

}

```
public class CommandHandlerImpl implements CommandHandler{

private final String regex = " ";
private IController controller;
private Socket client;

public CommandHandlerImpl(Socket client, IController controller){
    this.client = client;
    this.controller = controller;
}

@Override
public String getCommand(String abstractString) throws Exception {
    String result;
    String[] arr = abstractString.split(regex);
    String command = arr[0];

    String s = "";
    if(arr.length > 1){
        s = arr[1];
    }
    switch (command) {
    case "CAPITALIZE":
        result = controller.capitalize(s);
        break;
    case "BYE":
        result = controller.sayBye();
        break;
    case "SHUTDOWN":
        result = controller.shutdown(s);
        break;
    default:
        result="Command nicht gefunden!!!";
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String line, res;
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            line = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            res = null;
            if (line != null){
                res = getCommand(line);
            }
            if (res == null){
                break;
            }
            out.println(res);
            out.flush();
        }
          System.out.println("Verbindung von "+client.getInetAddress()+" beenden.");
          client.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

IController is an interface doing something with the String and returns a String so I can send it back to the client.
Is this good or how should it be for a good design?

Comment: It would be useful to show us the code for the `Server.java` that you said you've written to get a general idea of how you're doing it. Also, your question is quite broad the way it is because there are many approaches to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This class does the switch-case part to detect a command like "Say"
>   or "SHUTDOWN" and calls over an interface the corresponding method.
>
> Is this a good pattern?

Generally switch cases should not be used unless all the cases are **finalized** before-hand. If we know there are extension, as in your case, we should **not** use switch-cases at all.

For your case you can use either [Command](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) or [Strategy](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) as your need. If your set of operations are pretty much similar in logic, go with **Strategy**, otherwise **Command**.

As I read you question, I think **Command** is more suited for you.

I tried to outline the solution with Command pattern implementation, but it was somewhat hard to understand some of your code fragments. Generally you should be using comments whenever your code is not pretty much reflective for an outsider who reads it. I think you can understand with the source I have mentioned.

Additionally if you want to map a String from client to a desired Command object, use a Java Map. Don't use Switch-cases or if-else ladders which definitely makes it messy. Please raise questions if any. :))

Comment: thanks I will try to use the Command pattern later. But I need the swtich case because the server gets a String from the client so he has to differentiate which command to use or in case of command pattern which Command to load. Or is there another way to analyse the incoming stream from the client socket and response withe the right command?

Comment: You can skip the switch-case by using a map.  Map<String, Command>  map. Now you can have the desired command object via the String you are getting from the client. map.get("someString")   :)) Hope you understood.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. OK now I is the following design ok?:
A class **Server** with a Socket to start a Server and waits for a client to connect. After a client connects he creates a new Thread like in my code above ( **CommandHandler** ). And now the **CommandHandler** is the invoker. Then I have a **Command** interface and the **concrete** command classes. And the concrete classes invoke the classes who actual implement the **real** sending message to the client back. Is this right? Because using the pattern, I dont know who is who in my case

Comment: The primary focus of command pattern is decoupling the actual implementation of some operation from its consumer. In your example,  if you are doing something like this, it is the whole idea. public void performCommand(String commandName, String input){  Command command = map.get(commandName);  command.setInput(input); command.execute();  } . Now your code is pretty much extendable friendly. You just have to introduce new command objects when there are new ones. :))

Comment: ok thanks but the command pattern only solves a part of my design problem. Is the structure which I mentioned in my comment before a good design for a server?

Comment: and what about the Map<String,Command>? Who should know about that map to get the Commands?

Comment: ys.. your description is fine in overall. What do you mean by 'who should kow?'

Comment: like who should have acces to the map. Know the invoker ( **CommandHandler** ) has access to the map and can get the commands from there to invoke the command. I think this should be right.
But thanks my primary Problem with the design is solved I think

Comment: If you don't encounter with a situation where an outsider wants to access that map, keep it private to commandHandler. I think so far that class only right.? Skip any unnecessary exposures of any member. That's a good practice in all aspects :))